# selenium located a button is contain by iframe, can print button text but can't click

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
<iframe name="contentFrame">
  ...
  <a herf="#" class="zbtn znxt">next-page</a>
  ...
</iframe>
```

I want crawling the [comments](https://music.163.com/#/song?id=1220287), I located the 'next-page' button

```
driver.get(url)
# switch iframe
driver.switch_to.frame('contentFrame')
try:
    next_btn = wait.until(
     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'znxt'))
    )
    print(next_btn)
    next_btn.click()
except TimeoutException:
    ....
```

It could print the button's text, but the Console show me error msg [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gbMn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work. Considering the fact that you know the imports.

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#g_iframe")))
item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".znxt")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
```

It should also work:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#g_iframe")))
item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".znxt")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", item)
item.click()
```